# Download zip-compressed folder of xml files from liferay portlet

Tags: java, spring, download, mapping, liferay

I have a portlet, and using Spring MVC I want to download some dynamically created files. I mean I have List of String

```
List<String> xmls
```

,which contains the content of xml files, and I have some link in my view

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="exportForms" id="exportForms" />
```

If user click this

```
<a href="${exportForms}">download</a>
```

then, resourceMapping function have to make xml files form list of string, and pack them into compressed zip files.

```
@ResourceMapping("exportForms")
public void exportForms(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) {...}
```

And I do not know how can I do this. I found, how to download one, simple file, but there is no solution, how to download compressed folder of files, dynamically created from list of string.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Liferay 6.1

imports

```
import java.io.File;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.FileUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.zip.ZipWriter;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.zip.ZipWriterFactoryUtil;
```

And your resource method should look something like

```
    response.setProperty("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myarchive.zip");
    response.setContentType("application/zip");

    final ZipWriter writer = ZipWriterFactoryUtil.getZipWriter();

    for (String filename : xmls) {
        byte[] file = FileUtil.getBytes(new File("filename"));
        writer.addEntry(filename, file);
    }

    byte[] archive = writer.finish();
    response.getPortletOutputStream().write(archive);
```